# How to change the y label of contributions of column elements plot in factoextra package

Tags: r, pca

When I use `fviz_contrib` to plot contributions of column elements in `factoextra` package, the default y label is Contributions (%), I wonder how can I change to other text.

I used the following codes:

```
library(factoextra)
library(FactoMineR)
# Principal component analysis
# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
data(decathlon2)
decathlon2.active <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]
res.pca <- prcomp(decathlon2.active,  scale = TRUE)

# variable contributions on axis 1
fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice="var", axes = 1, top = 10, ylab = 'my label y' )
```

However, it prompted me

> Error in ggpubr::ggbarplot(df, x = "name", y = "contrib", fill = fill,  :
> formal argument "ylab" matched by multiple actual arguments

How to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code for that

```
# variable contributions on axis 1
library(ggpubr)
p <- fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice="var", axes = 1, top = 10) 
ggpar(p, ylab = 'my label y')
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks. Other `factoextra` function could use `ylab = 'my y label' ` directly in the function, why this one does not work?